# Nginx change links to 127.0.0.1

Tags: nginx, flask

I have a flask app running in a docker container, and I configured nginx to redirect all requests to this container. Here's my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_read_timeout 60s;
  }
}
```

On the frontpage I have a link to a subdirectory `<a href="/sub/dir/">Test</a>`, and when the page renders I can see it links to `http://example.com/sub/dir`. However when I click onto it browser shows `http://127.0.0.1:5000/sub/dir` and tries to reach my local.

Comment: Check what your browser is doing in the debugging tools when it ends up attempting to connect to the wrong address - does the browser get redirected by a 30x response, or is that the first request after clicking the good link?

Comment: Oh interesting. It got a `301 MOVED PERMANENTLY`

Comment: ok I think I know why.. my flask app also have a redirect..

Comment: Does `proxy_set_header Host $host;` help?

Comment: Yes Richard I was having the same thought. And tried that it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help from @Shane I found why.

My flask app have a redirect on that link to another page, after adding this to my nginx config it worked for me:

```
proxy_set_header Host $Host;
```

Comment: Sorry I answered my own question. But hope this helps others having same issue.

Comment: No worries, [you're allowed to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) answer your questions.